# Wordpress changes username in comments

Tags: php, wordpress, virus

I have a problem with wordpress. I have a big website with almost 3500 users and I am finding problems in the comments of my posts. There are a lot of them that are putting on the input for the name "domain dns" and in other cases it puts "list of domains". The comments are real but I don't know what is happening with the names. Another thing is that i have an input for websites and in all of this cases my page is filling the website input with finconta.xyz or avadoms.xyz
I have installed a plugin to search for malware but it doesn't find anything, so I don't know what to.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: does it happen when you post a comment yourself?

Comment: No it doesn't. I have tried to reproduce the error several times and I can't do it. I have also read the log of my wordpress antivirus and it says that those comments are made for real people with a real name but then wordpress puts "domain dns" as a name.

Comment: I really doubt these are real people.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's like you say but, do you think that the google recaptcha would resolve the issue?

Comment: It will help against bots, but people can always manually polute your comments. Blacklist the words finconta and avadoms as well, for comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is being spammed by robots. The comments look real because bots have become sophisticated enough nowadays to make comments look like humans have written it.

I recommend you to install the plugin Akismet and get an API key. This will decrease spam on your site drastically.

Comment: An alternative would be a plugin that allows you to use Google's ReCAPTCHA.

Comment: Using Captchas on commenting form just kill the user experience and thus usually get less comments on your site with a captcha. (saying from experience)

Comment: Very true. I'd consider it a last resort onl, although Google's ReCAPTCHA doesn't require that the user does anything other than tick a checkbox 9 times out of 10.

Comment: I have already akismet installed and the problem is still existing. I would try with google reCAPTCHA. Since 6/11 to 8/11 i have read a lot of comments with this name but nothing more since that date.

Comment: You are not seeing any more comments because the person behind the bot is not constantly using it. One such popular tools used is scrapebox.

Comment: But you have to pay for it and there is no demo for trying it.I am not gonna buy it to try...Thanks for your help!